# How to control styling of one DOM element from another DOM Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

Hi I have a Angular Material tooltip implementation. So when I hover my span I can able to see the tooltip. How can I conditionally change the background of the tooltip (Ex: Error show red background, success show green background etc.)

Component:

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    HostBinding,
    OnInit,
    ViewEncapsulation,
    ElementRef,
    AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dbs-tooltip',
    templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.scss'],
})
export class TooltipComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    @Input() content: any;
    @Input() position: any;
    @Input() type: string;

    constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-tooltip');
      }

    getToolTipClass() {
        if (this.type === 'error') {
            return 'error-class';
        } else if (this.type === 'success') {
            return 'success-class';
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span mdTooltip={{content}} mdTooltipPosition={{position}}>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
// md-tooltip-component {
//     div {
//       background: red;      
//     }
//   }


.success-class {
    md-tooltip-component {
        div {
          background: green;      
        }
      }

}
```

Any Idea guys? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use special selectors to style your component. Learn more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles). Read more about `::ng-deep`. Unfortunately, `::ng-deep` is going to be deprecated (later than `/deep/` and `>>>`, but still).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the angular directive `ngClass` in this way:

`<some-element [ngClass]="(your condition)? class-success : class-error">...</some-element>`

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to **customize a tooltip** and **not the element**.